# Android Studio. ошибка Intent

Tags: java, android

Привет всем

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            case R.id.button3:
                Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Подскажите почему выдает ошибку в предпоследней строке, а именно в слове intent ?

Comment: какие ошибки? Экстрасенсов заказывать или скажите ..

Answer (score 2):

сделайте так

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = null;

    switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.button:
           intent = new Intent(First.this, AboutActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       break;
       case R.id.button3:
           intent = new Intent(First.this, SecondActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       break;
```

в структуре `switch` вы создали нового переменного `intent` 2 раза так как `case`  не отрывает и не закрывает блок видимости переменного.

UPDATE: Правильно заметил `SorryForMyEnglish` нужно ставить `break;` после каждого `case`  в вашем случае

Comment: Ваш вариант сработал и ошибки в слове пропала, но в строке Intent intent = null; слово null никак не выделяется а при нажатие на кнопку с номером id=button3 возникает ошибка. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: напишите что за ошибка?